# Parse Text field with custom Tags and convert to HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, regex, replace

I have been struggling with this for hours.
Have tried searching online for a solution but everything I found wasn't exactly what I was looking for. Am desperate hope to get an answer.

I have a long string (mySQL text field) it contains text.
Dummy text sample :

```
There are many possible ways to minimize chances of cancer.
One such which has been proven beneficial is the use of anti oxidants
and various supplements.
[ARTICLE]
[TITLE]Green tea shows strong anti oxidant effects[/TITLE]
[DATE]Article published on May 2005[/DATE]
[BY]Department of Oncology research, University Hospital Denmark[/BY]
[TEXT]We test 54 subjects and given several vitmins, 
other group received placebo. [[MARK]]We concluded that green 
tea is an effective anti oxidant[[/MARK]]. We found Vitamin C to be
less effective.[/TEXT]
[/ARTICLE]

We also tested other supplements and also found interesting properties.
[ARTICLE]
[TITLE]Carrots ineffective for testicular cancer[/TITLE]
[DATE]Article published on October 2012[/DATE]
[BY]Oncology Journal, issue: 54[/BY]
[TEXT]Many people carrots are effective for several types of cancer.
In the research we did [[MARK]]we found that Carrots did lower
the cancer markers in test subjects[[/MARK]]. We cannot recommend
it as anti cancer.[/TEXT]
[/ARTICLE]
We will publish more research later on."
```

What I need to do is to parse that string and output it.
Notice that the string has two section (each starts with [ARTICLE] and ends with [/ARTICLE] and each of these sections have inner custom tags in them.
For every place that starts with [ARTICLE] and ends with [/ARTICLE] I don't output as is, I want instead to call my custom function to format it differently.

For example:

`function format_text_with_articles (ArtTitle, ArtDate, ArtBy, ArtText){
    // This is just a simple function I already have that gets
    // the params and formats a table with special formatting inside that makes
    // article extracts look nice.
    }`

So simply output all the text to the browser removing everthing between the tags [ARTICLE] and [/ARTICLE] (including the tags themselves of course) and these sections I out with special formatting that my function does.

Just notice that inside my custom tags TEXT tags I have special MARK example: tags[TEXT] blah blah blah [[MARK]]this is emphasized text[[/MARK]] [/TEXT]. For simplicity since MARK is the only tag that can be nested inside [TEXT] i put it as [[MARK]] (with double brackets]

How do I output all the text field as is, except for sections in between the [ARTICLE] tag and treat them as parameters send to a custom function ?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you building your own templating engine? There's plenty of pre-made systems for just this sort of thing, and PHP **itself** is a templating engine to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are wanting to do is entirely possible.  There are probably several ways to skin this cat, but this is how I'd go about it.

```
<?php

$full_article = '[ARTICLE]
[TITLE]Green tea shows strong anti oxidant effects[/TITLE]
[DATE]Article published on May 2005[/DATE]
[BY]Department of Oncology research, University Hospital Denmark[/BY]
[TEXT]We test 54 subjects and given several vitmins, 
other group received placebo. [[MARK]]We concluded that green 
tea is an effective anti oxidant[[/MARK]]. We found Vitamin C to be
less effective.[/TEXT]
[/ARTICLE]

We also tested other supplements and also found interesting properties.
[ARTICLE]
[TITLE]Carrots ineffective for testicular cancer[/TITLE]
[DATE]Article published on October 2012[/DATE]
[BY]Oncology Journal, issue: 54[/BY]
[TEXT]Many people carrots are effective for several types of cancer.
In the research we did [[MARK]]we found that Carrots did lower
the cancer markers in test subjects[[/MARK]]. We cannot recommend
it as anti cancer.[/TEXT]
[/ARTICLE]';



// MATCH ALL OF THE ARTICLE TAGS IN YOUR TEXT AND STORE EACH ONE INTO $matches
preg_match_all('~\[ARTICLE\](.*?)\[/ARTICLE\]~ms', $full_article, $matches);



// LOOP THROUGH EACH OF THE MATCHES, DO SOME FORMATTING AND REPLACE THE EXISTING CONTENT
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {

    $article = $matches[1][$i]; // TEXT WE WILL OPERATE ON
    $existing_article = $matches[0][$i]; // TEXT WE WILL BE REPLACING

    // PULL OUT EACH OF THE FIELDS WE WANT TO PASS ALONG TO OUR FUNCTION
    preg_match('~\[TITLE\](.*?)\[/TITLE\]~ms', $article, $match_article_title);
    preg_match('~\[DATE\](.*?)\[/DATE\]~ms', $article, $match_article_date);
    preg_match('~\[BY\](.*?)\[/BY\]~ms', $article, $match_article_by);
    preg_match('~\[TEXT\](.*?)\[/TEXT\]~ms', $article, $match_article_text);

    $article_title = $match_article_title[1];
    $article_date = $match_article_date[1];
    $article_by = $match_article_by[1];
    $article_text = $match_article_text[1];



    // SEND THE VARIABLES TO A FUNCTION TO FORMAT THE TEXT
    // THIS IS WHAT WE WILL BE REPLACING THE EXISTING TEXT WITH
    $replacement_text = format_text_with_articles ($article_title, $article_date, $article_by, $article_text);



    // REPLACE THE EXISTING ARTICLE TEXT WITH OUR REPLACEMENT TEXT    
    $full_article = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($existing_article, '/').'/', $replacement_text, $full_article);

}



// PRINT OUT THE FINISHED ARTICLE
print $full_article;



// THIS FUNCTION TAKES SOME PARAMS AND PRETTIES THEM UP FOR THE DANCE    
function format_text_with_articles ($article_title, $article_date, $article_by, $article_text) {



    // REPLACE THE 'MARK' BRACES WITH BOLD TAGS        
    $article_text = preg_replace('~\[\[MARK\]\](.*?)\[\[/MARK\]\]~ms', '<b>$1</b>', $article_text);



    // RETURN THE FORMATTED TEXT BACK TO THE CALLING 'FOR' LOOP
    return "<span style=\"font-family: VERDANA; font-size: 11px;\"><p style=\"font-weight: bold; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 5px;\">".$article_title."</p><p style=\"color: blue; margin: 0px;\">".$article_date."</p><p style=\"color: orange; margin: 0px;\">By: ".$article_by."</p><p style=\"margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;\">".$article_text."</p></SPAN>";



}
```